# Remove last word enclosed in backtick from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have the following string:

```
Input:
! Abc `xyzpqr` `abcd xyz` `test abc`
! Abc `xyzpqr` `abcd 123` `testabc`
```

I wish to remove the last word enclosed in the quotes.

```
Desired output:
! Abc `xyzpqr` `abcd xyz`
! Abc `xyzpqr` `abcd 123`
```

Using `rsplit()` I'm not getting correct output:

```
>>> text = "! Abc `xyzpqr` `abcd xyz` `test abc`"       
>>> text.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
Output:
"! Abc `xyzpqr` `abcd xyz` `test"
```

How to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) module:

```
import shlex

s = "! Abc 'xyzpqr' 'abcd xyz' 'test abc'"

print( shlex.join(shlex.split(s)[:-1]) )
```

Prints:

```
'!' Abc xyzpqr 'abcd xyz'
```

---

If you don't want to `!` quoted:

```
s = shlex.split(s)
print( s[0] + ' ' + shlex.join(s[1:-1]) )
```

Prints:

```
! Abc xyzpqr 'abcd xyz'
```

---

EDIT:

```
import shlex

s = '''! Abc `xyzpqr` `abcd xyz` `test abc`
! Abc `xyzpqr` `abcd 123` `testabc`'''

for line in s.splitlines():
    line = line.split(maxsplit = 3)
    line[-1] = shlex.join(shlex.split(line[-1].replace('`', '"'))[:-1])
    print(' '.join(line).replace("'", '`'))
```

Prints:

```
! Abc `xyzpqr` `abcd xyz`
! Abc `xyzpqr` `abcd 123`
```

Comment: @user3898160 What is your input string? And what Python version do you use?

Comment: @user3898160 online version: https://repl.it/repls/PrivateOpulentGigabyte

Comment: @user3898160 You can replace '`' with str.replace

Comment: @user3898160 replace them before shlex.split to `'` and then replace them back to backticks afterwards

Comment: How can we prevent removing of quotes from xyzpqr?